# Type-III Compensator design for Half-Bridge DC-DC converter control

Tags: power-electronics, dc-dc-converter, control, pid-controller, pole-compensation

Can anybody guide/share some technical documents which can help me to design type-III compensator for DC-DC Half-bridge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type 3 compensator can be built around a variety of amplifiers like an operational amplifier (op-amp), an operational transconductance amplifier (OTA) and a TL431 to cite the most popular options. The type 3 offers the following characteristics:

- a pole at the origin offers a high open-loop gain in dc (for \$s=0\$) and helps minimizing the static error (how \$V_{out}\$ deviates from the assigned target at steady-state).
- two zeroes: these zeroes can be placed at the resonant frequency of the buck converter operated in voltage-mode control but, usually, one of the zeroes is placed at a lower frequency to keep a good phase margin when the converter transitions into the discontinuous conduction mode (DCM) of operation (in light-load conditions).
- two poles: one is placed to tailor the phase boost to the right value (usually but not always true placed at the zero brought by the output capacitor equivalent series resistance or ESR) while the second forces gain roll-off at high frequencies (usually at \$\frac{F_{sw}}{2}\$) and provides gain margin.

The transfer function of such filter can be expressed in a *low-entropy* form as follows:

[image]

Please note the inverted zero in the numerator which lets you factor a leading term whose dimension is a gain. The configuration of the op-amp to form a type 3 compensator is here:

[image]

You can find the complete design procedure of such a configuration in a [seminar](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202010.pdf) I taught at an APEC conference in 2010.

Comment: @ Verbal Kint Thanks for your help. I will follow your seminar lectures. If I faced any issue regarding practical and simulation of this compensator I will get you back.

Comment: Glad if I could help. If you like the answer, perhaps you can acknowledge it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A half bridge is a buck-derived topology, and peak current mode doesn't work without some interesting tricks.

So we'll assume voltage mode.  You would place a pole at the origin for high DC gain.  Then place a pair of zeroes at the resonant frequency of the L-C filter to cancel the complex poles there.  Then a pole to cancel the ESR zero of the output capacitors, and a pole at around half the switching frequency to filter out high frequency noise.  Adjust the gain to get the desired crossover frequency (maybe about 1/10 the switching frequency.)

Beyond that we'll need a lot more detail about your circuit to give any additional information.

Comment: Well, Chris gave you a better answer than I did (thanks, Chris) and you should be able to follow his procedure for your particular design.  When I said more information I had in mind a schematic, or at least which controller you are using.  Maybe if you read through Chris's answer and are still stuck you could post a new question.

Comment: I am using LM5036 IC for half-bridge control. My Vinmax=60V, Vinmin=34 while Vout=12 with 20A load current. and switching frequency is 200kHz. what other factors do you need to know?